# Why can't fgets() nor fread() properly replace scanf() in my while loop?

Tags: c

Whenever I attempt to replace scanf with fgets or fread, the loop does not work as intended with '~' being unable to break the loop:

```
while (1){
    system("echo $PWD$");
    scanf("%s",kbinput);
    //fgets(kbinput,1000,stdin);
    //fread(&kbinput, 100, 2, stdin);
    if (strcmp(kbinput,"~") == 0)
        break;
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\n",kbinput);
    system(kbinput);
}
```

Comment: Read the [fgets manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "*If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.*". `fread` has that same issue and also it is not used properly as it will never automatically terminate the data with a NUL to make it a string - you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Maybe you didn't fully appreciate the implication. `fgets` will store the newline character. So comparing against something that doesn't have a newline, like `"~"`, will always not match. Either strip the trailing newline character from `kbinput` or add `\n` to the compare string.

Comment: `strcmp(kbinput,"~")` expects `kbinput` to point to a _string_.  With `fread(&kbinput, 100, 2, stdin)`, `kbinput` does not point to a _string_.  Post  a [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the assists. Greatly appreciated.